Second order PDE with Hessian
I am wondering if there is a existence/uniqueness result for the solution to PDE
$$
D^2 u = F (x, u, Du)
$$
with appropriate initial value conditions.
(Just to clarify, $u : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ and $F : \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^{d \times d}.$)
Since this is a natural object to think about, I am sure there should be some known results, but I do not know the words to google. I would appreciate any link/reference.

These are $d^2$ equations for one unknown, so if you pick an example at random, and you are to place a bet in Vegas, what would you do?

Can you give me some references for such systems?
